# Run WMIC queries under another user

Tags: remote-access, uac, wmic

I am trying to run a WMIC command under another user.

**I do not have their password but i have admin access on the machine**, is this possible?

Its simply to export mapped drives etc for backup purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Mapped drives are stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. 99 times out of 100 it is just easier to run a script from the user's context (say, a logon script) that writes their mapped drives somewhere.